# R 3.2 on travis - jsonlite error - "undefined symbol R_GetConnection"

Tags: r, travis-ci

I'm trying to test a package on R 3.2.5 using travis. My tests pass everywhere else for me, including on the other R versions on Travis and a version of 3.2.3 that I have available to me locally.

However, on travis with R 3.2 in my test that runs these lines:

```
# devtools::install_github("mnpopcenter/ripums")
ddi <- read_ipums_ddi(ripums_example("cps_00006.xml"))
ipums_view(ddi, launch = FALSE)
```

I get the following error:

```
unable to load shared object '/usr/lib/R/site-library/jsonlite/libs/jsonlite.so':
  /usr/lib/R/site-library/jsonlite/libs/jsonlite.so: undefined symbol: R_GetConnection
```

Any ideas on what's going wrong, or how to debug this? Since the tests pass on another machine with R 3.2, can I just assume it's a weird specific to how travis is setup?

If it's helpful, the full travis log is available here https://travis-ci.org/mnpopcenter/ripums/jobs/295909311

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `R_GetConnection` api is only called for `R >= 3.3`, so it should not be called by R 3.2 at all.

I think you are using a version of `r-cran-jsonlite` which was built using a more recent version of R, but then trying to load it in an older version. Try installing jsonlite from source.

Comment: Thanks! Was able to manually specify installing jsonlite in the travis config and sure enough, it fixed the failures.